# Delegating Handler in ASP.Net Web API returning incorrect status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net Web API with the following delegating handler:

```
public class AuthenticationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public AuthenticationHandler(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.Logger = logger;            
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = request.GetClientCertificate();

        if (certificate == null)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning("No certificate found on the request.");
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(
                () => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));

        }

        if (!IsValidCertificate(certificate))
        {
            Logger.LogWarning("Certificate found on the request is not valid. Thumbprint : " + certificate.Thumbprint);
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(
                () => request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }
    }
}
```

The handler is registered in Global.asax.cs. The site is hosted in IIS 8.5. 
The problem is instead of returning Unauthorized in case of a wrong certificate, it is returning a status of 500 Internal server error on the client side. There is no issue with correct certificate. Also, There seems no exception, if i put the code block in a try/catch. While debugging, the code returns the async task with unauthorized status code, but client receives 500. No error is logged in Event viewer. The Web API is using .Net 4.5.1.

Is there something I am missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was getting this generic error with WebApi, then I debugged using feddler, and a notice the real error. You should try this.

Comment: @Fals, What kind of error did you get? Was it something code related or framework related?

Comment: In my case was a DataBase error, but the chrome console did't show. When I debugged with Feddler I got the real one, Permission Denied on my Production DataBase generate a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @Fals, thanks for your help. Debugging with fiddler uncovered the error, which was assembly version mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Net.Http.Formatting assembly was the issue. The checked in version was 5.2.2.0 while the system was looking for 5.2.0.0. Added assembly binding redirect in the web.config and it solved the issue. The issue could only be uncovered by getting response from fiddler as suggested by @Fals. Server side debugging didn't help.